# Template function does not compile: expected primary-expression before ‘>’

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I wanted to wrap following line as function which takes parameter as a template type (to replace ConnectionManager for any other type):

```
std::shared_ptr<ConnectionManager> client = ConnectionManager::createClient<ConnectionManager>(broker, service_url);
```

So I created function that takes template parameter:

```
template<typename ClientType>
std::shared_ptr<ClientType> createClient(const std::shared_ptr<thrift::TServiceBroker>& broker, std::string url) {
        std::shared_ptr<ClientType> client = ClientType::createClient<ClientType>(broker, url);
        return client;
}
```

when I try to compile I get following error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
 std::shared_ptr<ClientType> client = ClientType::createClient<ClientType>(broker, url);
```

Kdevelop suggested following change:

```
template<typename ClientType>
std::shared_ptr<ClientType> createClient(const std::shared_ptr<thrift::TServiceBroker>& broker, std::string url) {
    std::shared_ptr<ClientType> client = ClientType::template createClient<ClientType>(broker, url);
    return client;
}
```

After this change code compiles and works.

createClient is defined in ConnectionManager parent as follows

```
template<class IMPCLASS>
static inline ::thrift::shared_ptr<IMPCLASS> createClient(const ::thrift::shared_ptr< ::thrift::TServiceBroker >& broker, const std::string& address)
```

I have two questions:

1. I don't understand why I got compilation error
2. I don't even know syntax that fixed the error

Please explain.

Comment: What's the change? Did you accidentally copy-paste the same code for your before-and-after?

Comment: @frslm Yeah, you right I fixed the code. Change was ClientType::template  instead of ClientType